# OpenRefine Remove Accents

Tags: openrefine

Is there an easy way to replace accents?

I have been using this formula:

```
value.replace("á","a").replace("Í", "Í").replace("ó","o")
```

Comment: Isn't there a search/replace tool built into the gui?  Could you not set it to replace one character with the other?  But in GREL, this might work :
value.replace("Old Value", "New Value")

Comment: Also maybe its a typo but this would change from this character into the same character, so it would be working just not as expected : e("Í", "Í")

Answer (score 0):

There's not a good way to do this simply using GREL, but you can switch your expression language to Python and use this:

```
import unicodedata

return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', value)
                  if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
```